# How to restore all the data from redis?

Tags: redis

I wanted to restore all the data I save using redis **BGSAVE** command.It saves the data to its default location **/var/lib/redis/6379/dump.rdb** .The data contains hashmaps,key-value  pairs .How to get back the data to redis from the dump.rdb file?
I am using RESTORE command but it is not solving the purpose!

Comment: Read the docs - `RESTORE` isn't meant for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just restart the server. On startup it will read the dump. It never has to read the dump during its operation, so there's no command for it.

`RESTORE` can be useful, but it's per key command. Meaning you have to parse the dump yourself, extract key names and their serialized values and only then call RESTORE for each key. Also, it was implemented to support migrating keys between two running servers. Not exactly your use-case.

Restarting the server is easier, isn't it? :)

Comment: I can do that. But when I am using **BGSAVE** ,it saves data to **dump.rdb** .Now to check restoring data from dump.rdb I use **flushall** command ,so it flushes all the data from redis-server and now when I check dump.rdb file then all the data flushes too from that dump.rdb file.I also try restarting as well but since flushall command flushes all the data from dump file too.. I am unable to test it. :(

Comment: Don't flush data. After the dump, delete a key or two, stop the server, start it back up and see that the key is loaded from the dump. (I'm assuming you don't use AOF file)

Comment: Nope,It is still not working.Can you please tell me the best practices with redis-backup storage(except- redis official documentation)?

Comment: Works for me. You have to kill the server forcibly (`kill -9 PID`), gentle shutdown won't work (it saves one last dump before exiting)